# Ruby- Not all lines being loaded but no error?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have this code:

```
    p "RC3"
    def self.rename_component
       # SOME CODE
    end

    def self.Rename(path,name)
       # SOME CODE
    end

    p "RC4"

    def self.Rename_And_Reposition_Components
      p "RC4.1"
      # SOME CODE
    end
    p "RC5"
```

Which outputs this:

```
"RC3"
"RC4"
```

When I have my code within #SOME CODE "RC5" doesn't print, but I also don't get any errors. Can anyone suggest what might be able to do to track down this silent error?

For completeness, the entire code block is:

https://pastebin.com/fj8tQzak

Comment: The code you have shown is not valid Ruby code. Please update your code to be valid (as in: you can copy it from the question and it will run) and so that it shows the issue you are experiencing. Try to reduce your code to a minimal example which exhibits your issue.

Comment: I've edited to remove an error I'd left in. It should run for you now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Have you tried running the edited code? Because the code in your question prints "RC3", "RC4" and also "RC5". Only "RC4.1" isn't printed because the method is never called. If you don't see "RC5", you're probably running different code.

Comment: The only difference between my code & what I've posted is I have code within #SOME CODE. I removed this as it makes it much harder to show what my problem is I think.

I can share all the code, but it adds another 100 lines & has calls to other files & functions.

I'm sorry I should have been a bit clearer in my question. I also find that this exact code runs successfully, but when I have my code within #SOME CODE the RC5 doesn't print, but I also don't get any errors. I'll edit my original question now to better explain this.

Comment: Well, the code you are showing works perfectly fine. We can't fix something that isn't broken. By simplifying your code, you've edited out the error's cause, i.e. you have removed too much code.

Comment: @Stefan I've added a link to my code. I tried making a halfway but stack overflow said it was too much code to post.

Answer (score 1):

The code (in your Pastebin) actually looks like this:

```
p "RC4"
def self.Rename_And_Reposition_Components()
  p "RC4.1"
  # ...
  for x in files do
    # ...
  end
  p "RC5"
  p "Loaded remaking components"
  # ...
end
```

Note that `p "RC5"` is still *inside* your `Rename_And_Reposition_Components` method's body.

Since the edited code in your question shows that line *after* the method, you are probably missing an `end` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. That would explain the behavior I'm having. Forgive me for my ignorance on this, but in VS Code I see different indentation to what you've just posted. 

https://imgur.com/a/KuT5leS

Comment: @BenGarciaDBSolutions try re-indenting/formatting your code.